# Flutter app on MacOS stops when trying to get list of usb connected devices

Tags: flutter, dart, hid, isolate

I use hid package for getting list of connected devices and receiving data from them. This code blocks UI if executes in main isolate, after wrapping it into compute() it may close app without any error message, there will be only message "Lost connection to device"

Comment: can you share error?

Comment: there is no error, just "Lost connection to device"

Comment: Did you get list of connected devices? @MaximKuzin